# Using functions in a select statement, can I use the result of a function in the same select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT [TransactionId]
        , min([Timestamp]) as [Begin]
        , max([Timestamp]) as [End]
        ,DATEDIFF(ss, min([Timestamp]), max([Timestamp])) as [TurnAroundTime]
```

Can I use the `[Begin]` and `[End]` names in the `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: No you can't (you can see if you try it). You can get those values in a subquery, then you *can* reference those attributes

Comment: The TSQL interpreter won't understand your aliases in this example. However, you could use a nested query and alias the result, then perform a SELECT statement from the aliased result (which will preserve your column aliases). For an example, refer to the answer provided by @LittleSweetSeas

Comment: You could use `[Begin]` in the `ORDER BY`, but that's because of SQL's Logical Order of Operations  >> essentially `FROM` > `WHERE` > `GROUP BY` > `HAVING` > `SELECT` > 'ORDER BY`

Answer (score 3):

No, not in the same statement as they are executed pseudo-simultaneously, thus Begin and End still don't exist when your **DATEDIFF** function is evaluated.

Anyway you could use a subquery - or even better, a Common Table Expression - for sake of readability:

```
WITH #computed AS (
   SELECT 
      MIN(Timestamp) AS [Begin],
      MAX(Timestamp) AS [End]
   FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
   [Begin],
   [End],
   DATEDIFF(ss, [Begin], [End]) TurnAroundTime
FROM #computed
```

On my system (SQL Server 2017), both solutions leads to exactly the same Execution Plan, so no overhead should occur with the CTE solution - test and check it on your system, though.

A side note: try to avoid the use of reserved word (such as Begin and End) in column aliases, to improve readability and avoid mistakes.

Comment: `A side note: try to avoid the use of reserved word (such as Begin and End) in column aliases, to improve readability and avoid mistakes.` >> I don't think this can be stressed enough. Reserved words are reserved for a reason, and they will cause more headaches than they are worth.

Comment: @Shawn I can't agree more: that's why I went OT, even knowing how harsh can be revisors here from time to time :)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

Within any single `SELECT` clause, all expressions are computed "as if" they're all being computed in parallel. This means, in particular, that you cannot have an expression that depends on the result of any other expression within that single clause - the value of the expression isn't "available" yet.

Of course, most products will actually evaluate expressions in some (unspecified) order but SQL Server enforces the language rules that prevent you attempting to reference those other expressions.

Bear in mind that in SQL you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. A decent optimizer should spot that multiple expressions use `MIN(Timestamp)`, say, and observing that it's a deterministic function, only *evaluate* that subexpression once.